# Shimano SPD pedal - visible seal ring

Tags: repair, pedals

I recently got a pair of XTR M9120 pedals. Today I noticed an elastic ring visible on the axel, and bits of grease on it too. The ring can be seen on the [service manual](http://si.shimano.com/pdfs/dm/DM-MAPD001-00-ENG.pdf)

[image]

This has happened on both pedals, although only one has signs of grease.

Does this mean I need to take the pedal apart and regrease? This has only happened after a few hours of riding (Less than 20).

**Pictures**

I have simply pushed it back in now by hand, but not confident it will stay there. Following pictures are after I pushed it in.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add a photo of the area you are talking about? The seal might be visible in its normal location or it may have come loose. Something may be wrong with the seal but you don't need to service the pedal bearings after 20 hours of riding.

Comment: The seal come off completely, and slides along the axel.

Comment: Can't upload photo taken by phone as its "too large".. But as I said, seal ring came fully out

Comment: You need to upload a photo if we're to help you. You probably have an option on your phone to resize, if not there are plenty of apps to edit photos. I won't recommend one as I do that sort of thing on the desktop or use the built in gallery app.

Comment: I have added pictures that show the ring after I pushed it inside. When I noticed the issue it was fully out, i.e not touching at the nut at all.

Comment: As it's happening on both pedals it might be a manufacturing or design problem. Either you can take it up with whichever vendor you purchased the pedals from or keep an eye on the seals and re-seat them if they start to come loose again.

Comment: Does anyone know where a replacement sealed can be purchased, or the part number?